# UITableViewController stops with (lldb) error after deleting Core Data record

Tags: core-data, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Using storyboards, I have a few views connected.  The first view displays all races.  Once a race is clicked it is passed to the 2nd view controller, which displays all runners.  The user can add/edit/delete runners on the 2nd view.

Everything works as expected if you add or edit records.  Even deleting records works as long as you're on the 2nd view.  If you have deleted any records, as soon as you press the button to navigate back to the original controller (standard UINavigation back button) the app stops and the only error is (lldb).

Any help is appreciated.  Please let me know if additional details would be helpful.

Comment: Too little information. Set breakpoints and figure out exactly where the app stops.

Comment: I have added breakpoints and everything appears as I would expect.  It is querying for the list.  The table is populating as expected.  The entire process works from end to end without errors.  After it has been rendered for about 1/2 second it generates the error (lldb).

Comment: If the only text you see is `(lldb)`, it almost certainly means that you've crashed due to memory corruption. The source code view probably includes something like `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. But there's not enough information here to tell how or why it's happening.

Comment: @TomHarrington you are exactly right.  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc).  What do I do next?  I uninstalled the app from the simulator and reinstalled it.  The same error occurred (different address).

Comment: Look at the line that caused it and see what object(s) it uses. Then try to figure out which one(s) might be corrupted. The static analyzer ("Product" menu --> Analyze) may help find problems.